# event not rendering by jquery to view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, fullcalendar

I am implementing the full calender in jquery in my asp.net mvc application by referring from [here](http://szahariev.blogspot.com/2009/08/jquery-fullcalendar-and-aspnet-mvc.html)

but as per this blog it should be render the events on dates given in the controller action. but it is does not. i followed exact same steps . i checked many times there is no mistake. so why should be this happening? please guide me

**Edited**

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult CalendarData()
        {
            IList<CalendarDTO> tasksList = new List<CalendarDTO>();

            tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
            {
                id = 1,
                title = "Google search",
                start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now),
                end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4)),
                url = "www.google.com"
            });
            tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
            {
                id = 1,
                title = "Bing search",
                start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
                end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(4)),
                url = "www.bing.com"
            });

            return Json(tasksList);
        }

        private long ToUnixTimespan(DateTime date)
        {
            TimeSpan tspan = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
     new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

            return (long)Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds);
        }
```

**Added Class**

```
public class CalendarDTO
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public long start { get; set; }
        public long end { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
```

**Site.Master**

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**View Page** I used Index page which given as default

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           events: "/Home/CalendarData"
       });
   });
```

And added div with id "calender".
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**Edited Quetion 2**

As you can see above my method returning the Json out put. but I am getting error as:
This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

So I just add the parameter as JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet to Json() .
 but it is asking for download the json output file. rather than this it must be redirect to view as usual , right ? why should this is happening?

Comment: What error were you getting? It might help if you could include some of your code.

Comment: not getting any error but it is showing calender bu not its events on dates

Comment: helloooooooooooooooooo is there any alive ??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a stupid question but did you include `jquery-1.3.2.js` and `fullcalendar.js` in your site? Remember that with the default ASP.NET MVC 2.0 project template, only `jquery-1.4.1.js` is included in the `Scripts` folder. Also I would recommend you downloading the latest versions of [jquery](http://www.jquery.com/) and the [fullCalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

Also here's another gotcha when returning JSON in the `CalendarData` action:

```
return Json(tasksList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Contrary to ASP.NET MVC 1.0, in ASP.NET MVC 2.0 the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is necessary if you want this action to be accessible over GET which is what I think the calendar plugin is doing.

Of course you would have seen this error if you used [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to analyze the AJAX request/response data.